# Deployment with "Container Registry" and "WebHook" in the Azure App Service not work correctly

Tags: azure-web-app-service, webhooks

I am trying to use the "FREE" layer of Azure App Services using the GitLab Container Registry.

To do the DEPLOY I am using WebHook, but I am not having success. I call WebHook to start Deploy (via Postman) and when analyzing the deployment LOGs, nothing happens.

The strangest thing is that at times it works, but it seems to be only once a day.

I call WebHook as follows:

```
https://$<my-app>:<token>@<my-app>.scm.azurewebsites.net/docker/hook
```

Are there any limitations for being a free tier?

Answer (score 0):

@Junior, please note that with Web Apps free tier there are a few quotas.

The two that you might be hitting are:

1. You can only use the CPU 3 out of every 5 minutes
2. You can only use the CPU 60 minutes every 24 hours

Source:https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/azure-resource-manager/management/azure-subscription-service-limits#app-service-limits

Windows Web Apps have a quota blade that allow you to see if you are actively hitting a quota. I would suggest checking there. Also check the diagnose and solve blade for your app to verify one of the above quotas are being hit.